# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/splash_screen.9.png"

Tags: android, android-xml, android-drawable, android-theme, android-styles

My app gets crashed on launch with below exception

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:
>   "res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/splash_screen.9.png"

2 points here,

1. I don't have `res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/` folder in my project
2. I have `res/drawable-xhdpi/` which contains `splash_screen.9.png`

I have `styles.xml` where in theme I am using this drawable. And, this theme is used in `AndroidManifest.xml`

Please help me.

Comment: Have your lib has it?

Comment: It just a POC project and not having any other libs except native android one

Comment: can you try to midify the file name and run it again? I worry some resources conflict.

Comment: Tried already. Also, I don't have any other resource file with this name. No chance of conflict.

Comment: put your nine patch image res/drawable/splash_screen.9.png. and try.

Comment: please put your `style` code.

Answer (score 0):

Please change your image name from **splash_screen.9.png** to **splash_screen_9.png** and 
copy/paste your image to **res/drawable-xhdpi/** from **res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/**

some time when we add any image to drawable folder,  v4,v7,v24 folders are created automatically and images are stored to that folders, So be careful when you add the images to drawable.

Please check below screen shot

[image: Screen Shot]

I hope its work for you.

Comment: Jfyi its a 9 patch image so format is correct. Also, I have already mentioned there no such v4 folder created by me.

Comment: Cut your image and paste again to res/drawable-xhdpi/

Comment: Can you explain what will happen if I do so?

Comment: It’s in drawable-xhdpi only and not in drawable